# Yocto in containers

Tags: docker, containers, yocto

I am new to Yocto so apologies for any mistakes.

I understand roughly that Yocto can be used for Embedded linux. (I got one example of installing it and running it on a Rapsberry Pi). I also read about running a emulator in the host computer.

My question is, is there a way to run Yocto inside a (docker) container? So that I can run this container on my PC

Answer (score 3):

Yocto is a tool for building a custom Linux-based OS for your chosen hardware target (e.g. Raspberry Pi, x86-64 PC, etc.). It also fully supports various devices emulated by QEMU, which is helpful for development and testing.

It is quite straightforward to run your Yocto builds inside containers during development (e.g. using a `ubuntu-20.04` container), and this helpfully keeps your development environment consistent.

However, if you would like to use Yocto to build a container that you can then run using Docker (rather than building for a specific board or emulator), then this is more complex and not supported out-of-the-box. Containers typically don't need a complete filesystem and kernel to run (this is Yocto's usual output), and so there is quite a lot of work required to trim it down and configure it to do this. There was a presentation at ELC 2018 about it ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSyLoHYxGLQ), [slides](https://elinux.org/images/6/62/Building-Container-Images-with-OpenEmbedded-and-the-Yocto-Project-Scott-Murray-Konsulko-Group-1.pdf)).

Perhaps take a look through the [Overview and Concepts Manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/overview-manual/intro.html), which explains a bit more information about the architecture, QEMU emulator, and development environment.

Comment: Thanks!. >t is quite straightforward to run your Yocto builds inside containers during development (e.g. using a ubuntu-20.04 container), >  By this you mean having a ubuntu container as a "Host" where to build the yocto images?

Comment: >chosen hardware target (e.g. Raspberry Pi, x86-64 PC, > I understand the Rpi case, but what do you mean x86-64 PC?  Does that mean I can build a linux-based OS for the PC and run it there? Inside a container? a bit of detail here will be appreciated

Comment: Yes, in the ubuntu-20.04 example, it would be the host PC. You are correct about x86-64 target - Yocto could build an OS that you could boot on it. It would not run in a container, although you could include the docker package if you wanted to use Docker within that OS.